# Problem with vedic accents in Tamil

Tags: fonts, fontspec, polyglossia

I have a problem with vedic notations for certain characters in Tamil.
Below I provide four cases to explain my problem.
The first line indicates the letter gu in which a number is used to indicate
a certain consonant in Sanskrit. In other words, I am trying to write Sanskrit text
using Tamil letters.
The second line is the same letter gu, but with a vedic accent at the bottom.
The third line is the same letter gu with a no-break space code U+00A0. If you look carefully,
the number 3 is shifted right. My intention is that the number 3 should be in the same
place as it appears in the first letter.
If, however, I use kern, as shown in line 4, I can place the number 3 in an acceptable position.

So, here is the problem. The first three lines can be written in a map file.
As an example, the first line could be written
as
g u > U+0B95 U+0BC1 U+2083
and so on for the first lines.
However, a kern, as far as I know, cannot be written in a map file.
I am looking for a solution which can be written in a map file.

I could also write a newcommand for gu as

```
\newcommand{\tgua}{{\char"0B95}{\char"0BC1}{\char"0952}\kern-0.25em{\char"00A0}{\char"2083}}
```

but this would mean that in the text I have chage every occurence of gu_ by {\tgua} where
the underscore _ is the bar at the bottom of the letter. This is not an elegant solution.
It messes with the readability of the text. An external program could be written to first
change all the ga_ to {\tgua} and save it in an intermediate program. But this is a cumbersome
process.

My program is

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newcommand{\tamv}[1][1.20]{
    \catcode`\^=12
    \catcode`\~=12
    \catcode`\_=12
    \fontspec{Noto Sans Tamil}}
\begin{document}
{\tamv {\char"0B95}{\char"0BC1}{\char"2083}}
{\tamv {\char"0B95}{\char"0BC1}{\char"0952}{\char"2083}}
{\tamv {\char"0B95}{\char"0BC1}{\char"0952}{\char"00A0}{\char"2083}}
{\tamv {\char"0B95}{\char"0BC1}{\char"0952}\kern-0.25em{\char"00A0}{\char"2083}}
\end{document}
```

and the output is

[image]

Comment: Try `{\tamv \char"0B95\char"0BC1\char"0952}\char"2083`, that is the brace grouping, so the subscript `3` prints in the main font, and set a main font e.g., `\setmainfont{Noto Serif}`.

Comment: Regular expressions (in expl3's regex function) may help, if the code pattern is consistently structured. Is `3` always anudatta?